# Declare in .h and initialize in .cpp

Tags: c++

I want to declare a pointer in my .h and initialize it in .cpp. For example an int pointer:

My .h class file:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

class Calc_ToF_low
{
private: 
    int telo[3];
public:
    Calc_ToF_low(void);
    ~Calc_ToF_low(void);
    double * CalcToF(int16_t * señal, int fs);
    long double * filter(long double *ganancias, long double *coeficientes, double *señal,int lensignal, int L, int control);
    void signal_p1_lowf(void);
    void avg_p1_lowf(void);
    void time_est();
};
```

My .cpp class file:

```
#include "Calc_ToF_low.h"

Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low(void)
{
    telo[3]={0,1,2};
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That's an `int` array, not an `int` pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're initializing large arrays with a constant value for all item, you can use this approach:

```
Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low(){

    memset(telo, 0, sizeof(telo));  //0 is the constant value
}
```

If you want to initialize your large array to some set of values that has no patterns:

```
int defaultTeloData[TELO_NUMITEM] = {2,4,1,5,6,1,7,82,41,6,134,88,1};

Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low(){

    memcpy(telo, defaultTeloData, sizeof(telo)); 
}
```

If your array values has pattern, use a loop and some formulas or constructors.

```
Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low(){

    for(int a = 0; a sizeof(telo)/sizeof(telo[0]); a++){
          telo[a] = dataFormulaForTelo(a);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low() // note no need to say void in C++
{
    telo[0]=0;
    telo[1]=1;
    telo[2]=2;
}
```

Or if you can use C++11, something like this might work:

```
Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low()
  : telo{{0,1,2}} // initializer list, will not work in "old" C++98
{}
```

Comment: What are the values?  If they're 0 to 99 then you can just use a for loop.

Comment: Or maybe just use a dynamic container (vector, list, etc)

Comment: it depends what are the values, if the are all zeroes for example then you can just write telo={}, but if they are random then obviously each one of them has to be written somewhere

Comment: The C++11 one shouldn't have parentheses.

Comment: @chris: it doesn't have parentheses.  Maybe you mean it should have one set of braces?  I can never remember which way it is in C++11.  :)

Comment: @JohnZwinck, I'm pretty sure both one and two sets of braces will work fine, but sorry for mistaking those for parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

You could just assign values to it by typing:

```
telo[0] = 0;
telo[1] = 1;
telo[2] = 2;
```

in your .cpp.

It may not be perfect for huge arrays but then you probably should assign the values from a file instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you could do it:

```
#include <array>

class Calc_ToF_low
{
private: 
  std::array<int, 3> telo;
public:
  Calc_ToF_low();
};

Calc_ToF_low::Calc_ToF_low()
: telo()
{
  for(unsigned i = 0; i<telo.size(); ++i)
    telo[i] = i;
}
```